# sql server - getting values from one table with columns' names stored in another table

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I have several tables.  These are somewhat simplified versions of the tables:

```
      UsersTable:
      UserId FirstName LastName MiddleInit Suffix    Age   Position 
      1    John       Graham     P.        Jr.     35     Analyst II
      2    Bill       Allen      T.        III     45     Programmer I
      3    Jenny      Smith      K.                25     Systems Engineer
      4    Gina       Todd       J.                55     Analyst II

     TableTypes:
     TableTypeId TableType
      1               Names
      2               Positions
      3               Age
```

TableTypeId is primary key in TableTypes and foreign key in TableFields.

```
     TableFields:
     FieldId  TableTypeId FieldName Description
     1           1         FirstName    descr1
     2           1         LastName     descr2
     3           1         MiddleInit   descr3
     4           1         Suffix       descr4
```

FieldId  is primary key in TableFields and foreign key in ModifiedUsersTable.

I need to fill ModifiedUsersTable with values from UsersTable so it looks like this:

```
       ModifiedUsersTable:
    Id  UserId      FieldId  Value
    1      1          1       John      
    2      1          2       Graham
    3      1          3         P.        
    4      1          4         Jr.
    5      2          1        Bill
```

etc.

I need to get only those columns from UsersTable that are listed in FieldName column in the TableFields table.  I don't know the number of rows (fieldNames) or the names in advance in the TableFields.
I thought I should try to use PIVOT.  I can get a comma separated string of the column names and then dynamically convert them into columns.
But it doesn't seem to give me what I need.  How do I fill ModifiedUsersTable?
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't your ModifiedUsersTable have an UserId Column?

Comment: Why would you want to have a table with this design? Especially since you have a perfectly good users table right now? You need to read up on why EAV tables are often a very poor database design technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDL for your data

```
create table UsersTable(
    UserId int, FirstName varchar(100), LastName varchar(100), MiddleInit varchar(100),
    Suffix varchar(100), Age int, Position varchar(100));
insert UsersTable select 
'1','John','Graham','P.','Jr.','35','Analyst II' union all select
'2','Bill','Allen','T.','III','45','Programmer I' union all select
'3','Jenny','Smith','K.',null,'25','Systems Engineer' union all select
'4','Gina','Todd','J.',null,'55','Analyst II';
create table tabletypes(
    TableTypeId int, TableType varchar(100));
insert tabletypes select
1, 'Names' union all select
2, 'Positions' union all select
3, 'Age';

create table TableFields(
    FieldId int,TableTypeId int,FieldName varchar(100),Description varchar(100));
insert TableFields select
'1','1','FirstName','descr1' union all select
'2','1','LastName','descr2' union all select
'3','1','MiddleInit','descr3' union all select
'4','1','Suffix','descr4';

create table ModifiedUsersTable(
    Id int identity, userid int, fieldid int, value varchar(max));
```

The script to populate **ModifiedUsersTable**

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = coalesce(@sql+ '
    union all
    ', '') + '
    select userid,' + right(FieldId,12) + ',' + quotename(fieldname) + '
    from userstable'
from tablefields
set @sql = @sql + '
    order by userid, 2'

-- print @sql -- uncomment to see the generated SQL
exec (@sql)
```